# Decomposing an xts Time Serie with STL()

Tags: r, xts, forecasting

I am trying to decompose an xts time-serie and create a data frame that holds 2 columns.

1. the date of the observation
2. The trend values of the decomposed time serie

The base Data frame has the following structure:

```
Date        x     y        z
2016-01-01 40419.35 12595 3.20
2016-01-02 44283.35 13904 3.18
2016-01-03 36277.23 10355 3.50
2016-01-04 42545.05 11929 3.56
2016-01-05 42402.22 13737 3.08
2016-01-06 49919.22 13661 3.65
...
2018-12-30 48719.22 13563 3.65
2018-12-31 49919.22 13661 3.65
```

Here's what I've done so far.

```
#1. Creating an xts object with weekly frequency
TimeSeries <- xts(x=Data[,-1],order.by=as.Date(Data$Date,"%Y/%m/%d")) 
TimeSeriesWeekly <- period.apply(TimeSeriesWeekly, INDEX = endpoints(TimeSeriesWeekly, on = "weeks"), FUN = colSums) 
attr(TimeSeriesWeekly, 'frequency') <-52
TimeSeriesWeekly<-TimeSeriesWeekly[,1] #keeping only the X variable I want to decompose

#2. Converting to a TS object in order to apply stl() decomposition formula
TimeSeriesWeekly <- ts(TimeSeriesWeekly[,1],frequency=52)

#3. Decomposing the TS object and distilling the trend
TimeSeriesWeeklyDecomposed<-stl(TimeSeriesWeekly, s.window="periodic")
TimeSeriesWeeklyTrend     <- as.data.frame(TimeSeriesWeeklyDecomposed$time.series[,2])
```

My problem is that the TimeSeriesWeeklyTrend data frame doesn't hold the date variable. How can I pass it?

Comment: Hello! Could you please post a dput() of your data, so we can give you back a reproducible answer?

Comment: @SantiagoCapobianco thanks for your comment. I posted above how the base data look like. Is this helpful? The dput() function created a very big file I couldn't post here :(

Comment: If the full dataset is too big to post, you can pull out a sample that represents the issue and `dput` that

Comment: dput(head(Data)) 


structure(list(Dat = structure(c(16898, 17616, 17026, 16959, 
17629, 17123), class = "Date"), x= c(40419.35, 44283.35, 
36277.23, 42545.05, 42402.22, 49919.22), y = c(12595, 13904, 
10355, 11929, 13737, 13661), z = c(3.20915839618896, 3.18493598964327, 
3.50335393529696, 3.56652275966133, 3.08671616801339, 3.65414098528658
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I found a solution, how can I post it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with the code below:

```
#2. Converting to a TS object in order to apply stl() decomposition formula
ts_data  <- ts(as.numeric(TimeSeriesWeekly[,1]),frequency=52)

#3. Decomposing the TS object with STL()
TimeSeriesWeeklyDecomposed<-stl(ts_data , s.window="periodic")

#4 Appending it to the initial xts object
TimeSeriesWeekly <- merge(TimeSeriesWeekly,TimeSeriesWeeklyDecomposed$time.series[,2])
names(TimeSeriesWeekly)[ncol(TimeSeriesWeekly)]<-"Trend"
```